# Login or create for Devise on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I intend to build a customized logic on Devise on Rails. Here is the logic: user can try to login, and if the does not exist, then it will create the account for the user. Just to skip the registration process.

Now sure how to hack into Devise. Please help!

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Sorry that I didn't make it clear enough: I have implement the on-create-validation on the user model to authenticate with another system. Logic is:
If success with another system's authenticator, then create a new user with the same password and login user.

Else login fail.

Comment: why the user can try to login if he/she has no account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to skip the registration process? I don't see any benefits.

First, the user can enter the wrong username or password by accident.
Second, the user can enter the right username, but the wrong password. So he/she already is a registered user, but still get a new account.
Third, when a new user is automatically registered, how does the user actually now what his username or more importantly, his password will be?

Personally, why not just add "Remember Me" or "Forgot Password?" to your login form. If, for any reason, the user doesn't want to enter his login data or simply doesn't know his password required to login he can use these options.

Or, if you are working with permissions, why not just make a guest user if someone is not logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You know that if someone make typo he will create new account and will be mad that all of his/her stuff disappeared? When there is small amount of user then it isn't problem. But when your society will grow then it can make you some black-PR. You should rather check by AJAX call that there is user with that email/username/nick and if not then show the registration form, but on other hand this can be security issue if your users are signing in using non-public data like email or if username is different from nickname shown on your page.

Answer (score 0):

What if they type in the wrong password or username on accident? Then you just automatically create them an account? IMO that would be a bad user experience. You either know your account or you don't. If you have an account and can't remember then you use the 'Forgot my ...'.  If you don't have an account, then you go signup. You could implement oAuth and use accounts from a multitude of sites (i.e. Github, Twitter, Facebook, etc.) that would make it easier.